# Are there any addons for Blender that allow users to create scripts (preferably with C++) to make video games using Blender?

Tags: modeling, game-engine

I know it is possible to create a game using Blender but I don't believe by its default configuration users can create a game by creating scripts, like in Unity for example.

Additionally if the addons for Blender are available, are there any tutorials on how to create a game using Blender with those addons?

Comment: I do not understand the intention of your question. C++ is no script language. You can create scripts with any text editor (the BGE supports Python). You can make a game in Blender just by pressing a button. BGE game descriptions are kept in .blend files. Python files can be referred from there. You can write Blender scripts (which is not a BGE script) to generate assets (including BGE code) to be used within the BGE. This is asset creation (before you even start the game).

Answer (score 3):

While there aren't any addons, you don't need any. Blender's game engine uses logic bricks, which includes a python controller for you to attach python scripts to any sensor input, or attaching a python controller to an always sensor will run your scripts repeatedly and the script can decide what input it responds to.

Python scripts can access any standard shared library function using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). A python module can also be [written using C/C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) as a large part of python already is, these binary modules can then be called from a python script. Note that the bge module that you use within any game engine script is already implemented using C/C++ code.

You may also be interested in [cython](http://cython.org/), which turns a python module into C or C++ code that can then be compiled into a binary python module. It can be an easy way to get the python module support code that you then add your C/C++ code to.

Answer (score 2):

Blender has a built-in game engine,and of course you can script it. Since Blender is Oprn Source, you could modify the C++ code if you want to use that language. The usual approach with the BGE is a combination of Python scripts and logic bricks.

The BGE is not abandoned, but forked into [UpBGE](https://upbge.org/) with the intention of re-integration of the fork into Blender 2.8.

Comment: Yes I know that Blender has a built in game engine but are you able to make scripts? and also is the game engine abandoned?

Comment: The game engine isn't abandoned. I am Blender will do some massive update on it's game engine in 2.8.

Comment: "google for it" isn't an answer.  Please elaborate so that anyone reading your post doesn't have to go elsewhere or do extra work to learn what they need.

Comment: I've updated my answer.